# Dynamic variable and value assignment in powershell

Tags: variables, powershell

How can I declare variables and assign values to them at run time.

*Reason*: I am fetching these variables values from sql server and these variable values are configurable in nature

*Code which I have tried till now*

```
   [array]$varArray = @($($ServerName),$($HostName)) 

 foreach($varname in $varArray)
        {
          $varname = "some test value"
        }

Write-Host $ServerName
Write-Host $HostName
```

Comment: @Ansgar Yeah ! I did figure it out and at the same time I removed the edited part. Thanks a lot for your assistance. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way of using dynamically named variables would be a dictionary:

```
$vars = @{}  # create empty dictionary

# add key/value pairs to dictionary:
$vars["foo"] = 23
$vars["bar"] = "foobar"
$vars["baz"] = Get-Content C:\sample.txt
```

Another way would be to declare variables on the fly:

```
$name  = "foo"
$value = "bar"

New-Variable $name $value

echo $foo
```

Or you could create a custom object and add properties as [Kyle C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15647562/1630171) suggested. That approach is similar to a dictionary, although technically different.

Comment: Note that for the second method you can also use `Get-Variable -Name $name -ValueOnly`.  You never actually need to know the name of the dynamic variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a NoteProperty to the object.

```
$varname | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name TestProperty -value "some test value" -PassThru
```

Also see this for what types of objects you can add a member to: [What objects are suitable for Add-Member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798258/what-objects-are-suitable-for-add-member)

Comment: I have tried replacing $varname = "some text value" with *$varname | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name $varname -value "some test value"* but it didn't work. I am quite sure I have missed the context of your answer, can you assist me as I am completely new to powershell. (started 5 hours back)

Comment: Do you have a little more information about the object type you are getting back? can you do $varname | Format-List ?

Comment: All those variables which is defined in array (ex:servername, hostname.. etc) are of string type only.

Comment: with this code *[array]$varArray = @($($ServerName),$($HostName)) 

 foreach($varname in $varArray)
     {
    $varname = "some test value"
    Write-Host $varname | Format-List
  }* 

I am getting

some test value
some test value

Comment: you don't want to assign $varname - can you try $varname.GetType().FullName without assigning anything to it?

Comment: *[array]$varArray = @($($ServerName),$($HostName)) 

 foreach($varname in $varArray)
        {
         Write-Host $varname.GetType().FullName 
        }* 

I am getting below exception

*Write-Host $varname.GetType <<<< ().FullName 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetType:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
*

I am not sure but is there any issue with the declaration with the array? My only purpose is to get variable values from sql server.